# Are numbers in interpolated strings in Swift affected by the locale?

Tags: swift, locale, string-interpolation

Are interpolated strings in Swift affected by the locale?

So, for example, if I have:

```
let beanCount : Int = 10
let s : String = "I have \(beanCount) beans"
```

Will this always give the following in every locale, even where non-latin alphabets might be used?

```
I have 10 beans
```

Is the same true for floating point where you could have a decimal separator?

If it does change, but I want it to be fixed, how could I ensure a standard format?

**EDIT:**

A little more clarification of my question:

I was in this case (although I didn't make it clear) looking particularly at basic types, such as the integer types (`Int`, `UInt32`, `Int8`, etc.), although floats where sort-of interesting as well.

My use cases are not really for generating strings for presentation to the user, but rather for generating strings for internal use in the application, for example as a file-name, an encryption key, password, or perhaps a dictionary key.

In this situation, I don't want the value generated affected by the locale, and I am really only interested in the basic types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of at least one type whose interpolation depends on the locale: NSNumber (on Linux): https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-789. The link is an issue called "NSNumber.description returns a localized version (e.g. with commas) on Linux", and shows that NSNumber has a localized (1000 -> "1,000") interpolation on Linux.

However, I think it is an actual bug that will be fixed, because my answer to your question is that string interpolation is not *intended* to be affected by the locale.

Now, *of course*, since types control their interpolation via the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol, *some* types could decide to interpolate in a locale-sensible fashion.

But types from the Swift standard library and Foundation do not.

Answer (score 3):

Interpolation uses `CustomStringConvertible` protocol so we can say that it all depends on the implementation of the given type.

To ensure a standard format, don't rely on `description` which was always intended mainly for debugging purposes.

If you want to present a string to the user then for numbers use `NSNumberFormatter` either with system or preset locale. If you are working with dates, use `NSDateFormatter`.

You maybe think that you won't have formatting problems with integers but what if you have `3000000` beans? Your current implementation would print `3000000` but what you actually want `3 000 000` or `3.000.000` or `3'000'000` (depending on locale). Always use number formatters and almost always you should use the system locale.

Comment: I see the manual entry on Int.description simply says: "A textual representation of self.".